# Would you use single quote marks around an awarded title like 'Hottest Designer of the Year'?

Tags: capitalization, titles

The sentence is: Randi proved herself to be worthy of the title of Hottest Designer of the Year with her gorgeous designs.

Does it make more sense as: Randi proved herself to be worthy of the title of 'Hottest Designer of the Year' with her gorgeous designs.

Comment: You already mentioned 'title' and capitalised it. Is that a real award? You could quote it, bold it, and italicise it too, but the more you do, the more sarcastic it becomes. By quoting it, you suggest mockery.

Comment: **☞ Hottest Designer of the Year ☜**

Comment: Weather Vane blows correctly again.